# Prove that $\{v_1, v_2, n\}$ is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $P = \text{span } \{ v_1, v_2\}$ be a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with normal vector $n$, show that $\{v_1, v_2, n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

It must be that $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is linearly independent (LI) by def of a plane, thus $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 = \overrightarrow{0}$ for $c_1 = c_2 = 0$.

It must follow that the coefficient of $n$ is 0?

Comment: @Mathematician42, shucks! I forgot I had already asked this question. So sorry about this. What can I do now?

Comment: No idea, you could have read the answers to your other question, in that case you would know the answer to this and there is no need to ask it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v_1$ and $v_2$ must be independent since the span a plane. Consider 
\begin{align*}
c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3n & = \vec{0}\\
c_1(v_1 \cdot n)+c_2(v_2 \cdot n)+c_3(n \cdot n) & = (\vec{0} \cdot n)\\
\end{align*}
By orthogonality we get
$c_3=0$. So we are left with
$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2  = \vec{0}.$$
Now use the independence of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: Why cant I just say since $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 = 0$ and $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, if we have $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2  + c_3v_3 = 0$, must have $c_3 = 0$?

Comment: I mean $0v_1 + 0v_2 = 0$ thus only possibility of addition is $0v_3$

Comment: @Amad27 two vectors could be linearly independent but when you have a third vector then the new set may no longer be independent. For example take $v_1=(1,0,0), v_2=(0,1,0)$ and $n=(1,1,0)$. Then $c_1v_1+c_2v_2=0$ will be satisfied only with $c_1=c_2=0$ but when we create a linear combination of the three vectors, then $1v_1+1v_2-1n=\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assume $$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3n=0,$$
now take the inner/scalar product with $n$.

Conclude