# Show vector exists in the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\{a, b\}$ a linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  If $c \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $(a\times b)\cdot c= 0$, then $c \in \text{span } \{a, b\}$

I know this is true but I cant prove it. How do I show that $c$ is a vector in the plane $P = \text{span } \{a, b\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Clearly $a,b,a\times b$ is a basis of your space. Now write $c$ as a linear combination of the above basis and take the inner product with $a\times b$.

Rmk: The following question is quite related [Prove that $\{v_1, v_2, n\}$ is a basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129942/prove-that-v-1-v-2-n-is-a-basis)

Comment: Can you help further? I dont see how to write it as the form?

Comment: $$c=c_1a+c_2b+c_3a\times b,\quad c_1,c_2,c_3\in\mathbb{R}$$